# Повернуть объект в сторону другого объекта не используя LookAt

Tags: unity3d

Я делаю Billboard Script (скрипт который будет поворачивать объект к камере, как в Doom или Baldi) и пытаюсь применить разные оптимизации. Дело в том, что он должен быть максимально производителен, ведь у меня есть несколько сотен объектов которые нужно поворачивать к камере. transform.LookAt - одна из проблем моего скрипта, ведь эта функция очень дорогая. Как вручную повернуть объект к камере не используя LookAt? Буду благодарен.

Уточнение: поворачивать нужно только по оси Y

Comment: Тебе просто спрайт нужно повернуть лицом к игроку? Используй [шейдеры](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Billboards). По ссылке как раз billboard шейдер, модифицируй как тебе нужно.

Comment: @KOTlK, Я бы рад использовать шейдеры, но моя игра уже построена на скрипте, а подстраивать её под шейдер будет слишком утомительно. Также я плохо разбираюсь в шейдерах, поэтому я не думаю что смогу изменить его под свои нужды.

Comment: Радиана вектора находится через метод atan2

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел способ как это сделать:

```
var offset = cameraCurrent.transform.position - transform.position;
offset.Set(offset.x, 0, offset.z);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3.back, offset, Vector3.up), 0f);
```